# Laravel 7, Missing required parameters for [Route: /xxxxx] error

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-7

I am trying to pass a value from a view to a controller and use that value in a query. I am getting Missing parameter error. This is my code.
View:

```
<a href="{{ action('/first_letter', ['f_letter'=>'A']) }}">A</a>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/first_letter/{$f_letter}','PtoductController@first_letter')
    ->name('first_letter');
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{  
    $products = DB::table('products')
            ->join('families', 'products.id_family', '=', 'families.id')
            ->select('products.name')
            ->where('products.name', 'like', $f_letter.'%')
            ->get();

     return view('product.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Comment: update your route to this `Route::get('/first_letter/{f_letter}','PtoductController@first_letter')->name('first_letter')`

Comment: why {$f_letter}? try {f_letter} in the route definition

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems

**first**, fix your route to be like this

```
Route::get('/first_letter/{f_letter}','PtoductController@first_letter')
    ->name('first_letter');
```

when you pass a `wildcard` in route it is written like this `{f_letter}` not `{$f_letter}`

**Second**, in your controller you need to pass the `wildcard` in your method as `parameter` like this

```
public function index($f_letter)
{  
    $products=DB::table('products')
            ->join('families', 'products.id_family', '=', 'families.id')
            ->select('products.name')
            ->where('products.name', 'like', $f_letter.'%')
            ->get();

     return view('product.index', compact('products'));
}
```

you can read more about routing [parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters) here

At last you can make your `a` tag more clear like this

```
<a href="{{ route('first_letter', 'A') }}">A</a>
```

Comment: Just as an observation: In case you don't want to inject the param in the function, you can also get it from the request object: ```$letter = request('f_letter');```

Comment: yah that is another way, but in case he use a form

Answer (score 0):

**First**, are you sure the controller name is "**PtoductController**"? Shouldn't it be called **ProductController**?

**Then**, if the controller name is correct, remove "$" from the link you call from the controller.

```
Route::get('/first_letter/{f_letter}', ['uses' => 'PtoductController@first_letter'])
    ->name('first_letter');
```

**Last**, Put $f_letter as a parameter in the "first_letter" function.

```
public function index($f_letter)
{
   //your code
}
```